# z-index is not working on right click

Tags: jquery, css, contextmenu, z-index

I am trying to implement a contextmenu that appears on right click to div with class `contextFolder` which has `z-index: 1000`.

To do that, I bind contextmenu event to divs with JQuery. This is working fine. I want this contextmenu to disappear when

- User left clicks anywhere on the screen,
- User right clicks anywhere on the screen except any other `div.contextfFolder`

If while contextmenu is opened and right click happens on other `div.contextFolder`, I want my current contextmenu to disappear and open a new one on new `div.contextFolder`.

To do that when I show to contextmenu,

- I also create a overlay with `height: 100%`, `width: 100%`, and `z-index: 100`.
- I bind left click event to this overlay such that when it is clicked,

  - overlay is removed,
  - contextmenu is hidden.
- I also bind contextmenu to `overlay` to hide contextmenu and remove `overlay` when right clicked to any point except another `div.contextFolder`
- To prevent left click event of overlay on contextmenu, I also assign `z-index: 101` to contextmenu.  (z-index of overlay is 100)

This seems all fine to me.(I am newbie in CSS, so I might be missing something very obvious).

All working fine, except when I right click on `div.contextFolder` when a contextmenu is already open on another `div.contextFolder`, it goes to contextmenu event of overlay (which hides to current one). I want new one to open.

I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox latest versions.

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvSXd/6/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a fiddle for you. 
All I did was rework your javascript.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4DD13/z4WrH/)

Hope that helps you.

PS: I also added other code which checks to see whether clicks after the initial opening of a menu are clicks on a child of the menu

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
 bind('contextmenu' , function(e){
             $(".folderContextMenu").css( {position:"absolute", top:e.pageY, left: e.pageX, zIndex: '101'} );
                e.preventDefault();
                //alert('not working');
                return false;
            }
```

The problem is that you are not moving the context menu again. It stays at the old position. Therefore I have a bit changed the bind-function. But if you are using the overlay, and apply the bind function to it, the menu shows up everywhere, that's the second problem.

Here is the complete, changed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvSXd/9/)

EDIT: I have used the window onclick method, look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nvSXd/10/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nvSXd/11/) is the proof that the menu is rebound.

Comment: thanks for answer but in updated fiddle, if you right click on overlay (not on contextFolder), it moves context menu also. Also I dont want it to move but rebind it, since I will need the contextFolder that is right clicked.

Comment: thank you for your time. it is working in fiddle but I have other events on my page that are not working when I use window onclick method that is why I accepted L4DD13's answer. Hope, you don't mind.

Comment: No, I don't. His answer also correct and it's your choice, of course ;)